# Run function in a separate process to avoid segfault

Tags: php, unix, ubuntu

I have a big function, that I have to call a 50-100 times. Previously I used bash script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
 RET=0
 until [ ${RET} -eq 1 ]; do
  php /scripts/cli.php $i
  RET=$?
 done
done
```

But i`m not good in bash scripting while I need to enchance logicwith returned values, so I tried to implement this in pure php with a function like that:

```
<?
require_once('cli.php');
for($cnt=1; $cnt<=50; $cnt++){
 $cli = cli($cnt);
}
?>
```

But this approach results in segmentation fault after 10-15 cycles. Is it possible to run function in a separate process loke it was in bash script and clean resources to avoid memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could look into proc_open if you need access to the child processes stdin/stdout/stderr or you could use the simpler functions: exec() or passthru().

That said.. PHP should not segfault, there must be some sort of buggy extension you're using. I'd focus more on fixing that than creating workarounds.